# When I upload sound file and convert sampling rate with librosa, memory usage is too big

Tags: nginx, file-upload, out-of-memory, gunicorn, librosa

I am developing a web using flask + nginx + gunicorn to convert sampling rate on file upload.
When I upload and convert an audio file(mp3 or wav) of about 40MB, I could see a sharp increase in RAM usage.
Although I use aws lightsail(memory 2GB), instantaneous memory usage is over

Log are
At nginx error.log, upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
At sys.log,  OOM and memory killed

I'm using virtual memory to make one file work somehow, but I want to make it simultaneously used by several people, so I'm trying to solve the memory problem.

Question

1. Why does the upload consume much more memory than the size of the file?
2. What is the solution?

code is using librosa.
Function memory_usage was added to see memory usage history.

[#1] memory usage:  153.62500 MB

[#2] memory usage:  488.25391 MB

[#3] memory usage:  219.86719 MB

[#4] memory usage:  220.30078 MB

'''
'

```
import psutil
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import librosa, soundfile

import librosa.display
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from datetime import datetime
import os
import io
from pydub import AudioSegment

#memory
def memory_usage(message: str = 'debug'):
    # current process RAM usage
    p = psutil.Process()
    rss = p.memory_info().rss / 2 ** 20 # Bytes to MB
    print(f"[{message}] memory usage: {rss: 10.5f} MB")
    file = open(f"C:\\Users\\kimkunyu\\Desktop\\mmmmm.txt","a")
    file.write(f"[{message}] memory usage: {rss: 10.5f} MB")
    file.close()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_pybo():
        return render_template('main.html')


    @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def upload():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            audio_data = request.files["lc"]
            memory_usage('#1')
            if audio_data:
                filename = secure_filename(audio_data.filename)
                src = f"pybo/sound/{filename}"
                audio_data.save(src)
                stem, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(filename)
                if fileExtension == '.mp3':
                    audSeg = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
                    ##
                    os.remove(src)
                    src = f"pybo/sound/{stem}" + '.wav'
                    audSeg.export(src, format="wav")

                sr = librosa.get_samplerate(src)
                memory_usage('#2')
                audio_data, sr = librosa.load(src, sr=sr // 6)
                # print(sr)
                # print(audio_data.shape)
                # print(audio_data.dtype)
                # print(len(audio_data))

                memory_usage('#3')
                new_filename = f'{filename.split(".")[0]}_{str(datetime.now())}.wav'
                new_filename = new_filename.replace(':', "_")
                os.remove(src)

                save_location = f'pybo/output/{new_filename}'

                soundfile.write(save_location, audio_data, sr, format='WAV')
                memory_usage('#4')

                return render_template("download.html", save_location=save_location)


    @app.route('/download', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def download():
        save_location = request.form["save_location"]
        with open(save_location, 'rb') as fo:
            return_data = io.BytesIO()
            memory_usage('#5')

            return_data.write(fo.read())
            memory_usage('#6')
        # (after writing, cursor will be at last byte, so move it to start)
        return_data.seek(0)

        os.remove(save_location)
        return send_file(return_data, as_attachment=True, download_name='converted_file.wav')
    return app`
```

Comment: What does "make it used simultaneously by multiple people mean"?

Comment: What format is your 40 MB file?

Comment: What is the memory usage that you observe?

Comment: 1. Currently only one person can use it due to memory issues. so i wanna reduce memory usage.

2. mp3 or wav

3. 
[#1] memory usage:  153.62500 MB

[#2] memory usage:  488.25391 MB

[#3] memory usage:  219.86719 MB

[#4] memory usage:  220.30078 MB